# plotly 3D Topographical 3D Surface Plot with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, plotly

I have a coordenates points cloud in a padas dataframe

[image: dataframe]

[Following](https://plot.ly/python/3d-surface-plots/#passing-x-and-y-data-to-3d-surface-plot), I want to plot a ploty surface diagram but Surface method needs a 2D array in z param and i don't know how to build it.

```
go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z, x=x, y=y)])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to grid your data first. I created an example from your  data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

#Read data
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=0, delimiter='\t')

#Create meshgrid for x,y
xi = np.linspace(min(data['x']), max(data['x']), num=100)
yi = np.linspace(min(data['y']), max(data['y']), num=100)

x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)

#Grid data
z_grid = griddata((data['x'],data['y']),data['z'],(x_grid,y_grid),method='cubic')

# Plotly 3D Surface
fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(x=x_grid,y=y_grid,z=z_grid,
                           colorscale='viridis',showlegend=True)
)

fig.show()
```

[3D surface from your example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHkKz.jpg)

You can use different methods for gridding (cubic, linear, nearest)
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

Answer (score 0):

**It's definitely a bad design that `go.Surface` doesn't support directly using `DataFrames` as parameters.** Imagine you swapped `x` and `y`, for example: `x=df.index, y=df.columns, z=df.values`. You won't notice that your x-axis data isn't fully displayed if you don't scrutinize it carefully. That's because you reversed `x` and `y`, which gives you the wrong result!